# При нажатии на элемент выдвижного меню программа вылетает

Tags: java, android

Имеется код:

```
package asus.example.com.notes1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;
    private String[] titles;
    private ListView drawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        drawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles));
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        if (savedInstanceState==null){
            selectItem(0);
        }
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {
            public void onDrawerOpened (View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
        setIntent("This is an example test");
        return true;
    }

    private void setIntent(String text){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        boolean drawerOpen = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_create_order:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OrderActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position){
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (position){
            case 1:
                fragment = new PizzaFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new PastaFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new StoresFragment();
                break;
                default:
                    fragment = new TopFragment();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
        setActionBarTitle(position);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
    }

    private void setActionBarTitle(int position){
        String title;
        if (position==0){
            title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        }
        else {
            title = titles[position];
        }
        getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Задача - при нажатии на элемент выдвижного меню, должна открываться новая активность, например Home или Pizza. Однако вместо этого программа закрывается, хотя ошибки не выдает. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите так:

```
   drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {
        public void onDrawerOpened (View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, OrderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }

    };
```

В методе onDrawerOpened -  открывается активность)